# How to use IAP for a sticker iMessage Application

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, imessage-extension, ios-stickers

I watched a tutorial on how to create IAP non-consumable for a regular App but can the same code be used for iMessage stickers? There are no resources out there on how to create IAP for iMessage stickers.

Comment: I don't want to make a regular App. I just want to create a sticker pack in iMessage Application with IAP

Comment: Starting over, because I'd like to be constructive. So if you *cannot* find a resource for what you want to do.... can you provide something/anything in the AppStore that does what you want? (If not, consider that the reason why is because you won't be able to do this.)

Comment: Absolutely, I just started two days ago and I have no coding experience so I apologize for my confusion. An example of what I want to accomplish is the ‘‘Cookie Monster’’ Stickers that can be found on the iMessage App Store. The first 23 stickers are free, then there are 35 stickers bellow the free ones that the user can purchase for $0.99 cents.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to sell your stickers on the iMessage app?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want the first 10 stickers to be free and then the rest to be unlocked with IAP

Comment: any updates or found solutions for this? I'm also struggling to find guidance on how to create sticker packs with IAP / freemium model.